# Changing the property of an imported class in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to change the properties of an imported class in eclipse? Specifically, I am trying to change the `serialVersionUID` property
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason to change the serialVersionUID is if you want to purposely break compatibility with all existing serializations or if incompatible changes are made to the structure of the class. Heres a [list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6678) of incompatible changes.

But if you need to change it, you can generate the serialVer your jvm is probably using using the serialver tool:

serialver -classpath whatever com.foo.bar.MyClass

Manually set the serialVerUID in your class and it should match and be able to load, assuming you haven't changed the class in such a way as to invalidate. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If the code of the imported class is compiled, then no. The `serialVersionUID` property is of type `long`, and cannot be changed.

You can, however, cast it to any type you'd like, as long as it's feasible. If it's not, you can convert it.